# Row and Column Index in Javascript table

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner at Javascript, and so this might seem like a basic question.

I created a HTML table from a JSON file using javascript. The table, called "JsonTable", has 7 columns. I need to create a scatter plot, plotting column 4 and column 6. How do I select these columns? I can't find anything which will let me index the columns to select them.

Thanks!

Here is my code: when I run it, a table with 7 columns appears. I need to plot column 4 and column 6..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>


</head>
<body>



<div style="margin: 20px auto; width: 500px;">
<table  border="1" cellpadding="5" id="jsonTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
    var columnSet = [];
   var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $("#jsonTable").append(headerTr$);



    return columnSet;
}



$.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {

    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {

            var cellValue = data[i][columns[colIndex]];

            if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $("#jsonTable").append(row$);
    }
});

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far..

Comment: show us the code. Do you want to use just javascript or is jquery allowed?

Comment: I just added the code :) I am not sure how that will help, as the code simply creates a table. I now need to use column 4 and 6 of the table and plot them against each other...

Comment: Do you still have the JSON available that you used to create your table? I'll be much easier to create the scatter plot from raw data than from parsing an HTML table.

Comment: I do have the JSON available. How to I create the scatter plot from the raw data?

Comment: But the problem with that is that while right now my JSON has 30 entries, soon it will have 1 million, so i will need to create ranges for variables to be plotted. Right now, could you please help me with my original question: how to index two columns in a multi column table to plot them? Thanks!

Comment: If your concern is performance, then parsing the DOM will be way slower than parsing your data.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little broad. To break it down a bit, first you should be asking "how do I get data in the format that represents a scatter plot," and then "how do I draw the scatter plot."

Since the JSON data you're receiving is an array of arrays, you want to transform each item of the array into a new format, a list of x/y pairs. The `.map` method of array is good for that:

```
var points = data.map(function (item) {
  return { x: item[3], y: item[5] };
});
```

This will give you something like:

```
[
  { x: 15, y: 69 },
  { x: 9, y: 295 }
]
```

If you also wanted to select a *range*, you could use `.slice` prior to `.map`:

```
var points = data
  .slice(startIdx, count)
  .map(function (item) {
    return { x: item[3], y: item[5] };
  });
```

How you draw the scatter plot from there depends on what your requirements are, but it will essentially boil down to looping through the data with some draw commands, plugging the data into a scatter plot library, or some other sort of operation.

Comment: Hi! I think that I probably made it a little complicated. The table with the id JsonTable in the code has 7 columns. I need to plot column 6 in the x axis and column 6 in the y axis. I don't need to splice the data at the moment, just need to plot all entries of column 6 against column 4. :) I'll be grateful if you could let me know how I can do that :)

Comment: That is what this code should be doing. I assume by "column 6" you mean the sixth column, which will come from index 5, and column 4 would be index 3.

Comment: Why take the data, shove it into a table, then take the data back out of the table, and shove it into more data?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by index 5 and index 3? As in, how do I write that in the code? Do I do that after creating the table with id jsonTable?

And yes, it doesnt make much sense to do that, but I need to show my professor both the html table and the plot for now..

Comment: That's what `{ x: item[3], y: item[5] }` is doing. `[]` is how you access indexes. `0` is the first item (it's zero-based).

Comment: Oh ok.. So here, item would be replaced by jsonTable, right? Thanks!